# Is there a convention for renaming document.querySelector etc in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conventions

In the unlikely event that I am

1. writing JavaScript
2. don't want to use a framework like jQuery
3. want to replace frequent calls to 'document.querySelector' with something shorter
4. want my code to still be readable and familiar to new developers who look at it

Are there any abbreviations that are *commonly used* to replace querySelector, querySelectorAll, etc?

> This is a question about naming conventions. **I'm not asking how to
> abbreviate a long function name**. For reference, you can do it like
> this:
>
> ```
> var queryAll = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
> ```

Comment: I don't think questions about naming conventions are well suited for SO - as much as I'd like to know the answer to this, too.

Comment: No, there is no such convention.

Comment: Most of the time there's no need to make abbreviations because you don't want to directly interact with the DOM.

Comment: The most common name for `querySelector` functionality is `$`. That's what jQuery, sizzle (the selector library that jQuery use), prototype, Google Chrome debugger etc. use

Comment: There's no conventions I'm aware of, outside of fluent query interfaces like jQuery or Eloquent and low-level abstractions like a DBAL.

Comment: @Dan Philip: You might want to read the highlighted portion of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Furthermore, I don't think its a good idea to use abbreviations. Why change the Javascript API for no other reason than to make it shorter?

You could reuse something like `$`, but then you might give the reader the impression that you are using an existing library that uses that abbreviation.

Some other considerations:

- What happens if you later decide to add a library that uses the same abbreviation? You need to refactor your code
- What happens if someone wants to reuse some of your code and your abbreviations conflict with there code or libraries.
- With modern editors / IDEs, using abbreviations will not likely reduce the amount of typing if you are using auto fill
- For someone learning Javascript it will most likely make make your source confusing to read.

I've done this in the past only to regret it later. Makes your code less portable.

Short answer. I don't recommend it.

Comment: This is a nice post but it does not answer the question _Is there a convention for renaming document.querySelector etc in JavaScript?_ – if you just add 'No.' or 'Not that I know of" or "No, because…" at the start I will happily accept it.

Comment: Edited my post to start with the answer.

Comment: Nobody is talking here about unreasonable abbreviation. But `document.querySelectorAll` ... c'mon ... , if it must be under document, they could at least make it `document.select()` / `document.select_one()` or directly on global level like `Selector()` ...

Comment: @StevePallen points are valid. I still prefer brevity, so with his caution in mind to distinguish Vanilla JavaScript helpers from from 3rd party libs, I'll use v$ and v$$.

Answer (score 1):

**not that I know of**

## Let's make some

### Modern JS oneliner usable in all modern browsers

```
Selector = (s,c) => (c ?? document).querySelectorAll(s);
```

#### Usage

```
// search in the whole document
Selector('.some, .randomClasses');

// search only in the context of someParent
var someParent = Selector('.give .me .parent')[0];
Selector('img', someParent);
```

Leverages [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and [grouping operator ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping)

Unless not obvious, this always [returns the same stuff, `querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#return_value) would, you can easily adjust this to do similar with `querySelector` maybe naming it e.g. `SelectorOne`, you get the picture...

### More robust JS with compatibility check

Usage stays the same, but in case someone's worried about it breaking stuff:

```
if (typeof Selector != "undefined") {
  console.warn('CONFLICT WITH Selector! - please address this issue!')
} else {
  function Selector(selector, current_context) {
    if (typeof current_context == "undefined") {
      current_context = document;
    }

    return current_context.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
}
```

#### Why I chose naming "Selector"

- I **chose** the naming with uppercase 1st letter **on purpose**, since interfaces are usually named that way and it slightly decreases risk of conflicting variable for a piggy code on global level
- I **didn't** name it <del>`Select`</del> because that **is ambiguous** and
  could imply [`Selection` which is a different experimental interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)
- **`Selector`, in HTML&CSS world, is specific enough :)**

PS: I really do wonder why they made it so long, when that was the main reason people were using heavy libraries (like old jQuery) instead of doing it in plain JavaScript... I really do hope it was a technical reason...

Comment: That's a nice start. My criticism is if the point is to create less-verbose commonly used DOM commands, maybe we can make it even shorter than *Selector*. Using just the $ is confusing with jQuery, but maybe we could take inspiration from that and do a variation. Something like `$all` for `document.querySelectorAll`, `$one` for `document.querySelector`, and `$el` for `document.createElement`. They are short, understandable, and consistently named with each other.

Comment: @ChrisBroski I understand the intention, but the reason jQuery (and other libraries) chose `$` in particular is that it's a valid variable name that is NOT commonly used if at all (for non-library purposes). Whereas `$all`, `$one`, `$el` will be quite common especially when combined with jQuery effects. But I agree the naming could be shorter, but it should most likely be starting with an uppercase letter (like `Sel`), or if you don't have a library, just put it in `$`.

Comment: Yeah, I think it could be better too, just not sure what. I am not a fan of starting with a capital letter though because I thought the convention was functions that start with a capital letter are constructors.

Comment: @ChrisBroski and you'd be right, that surely is the convention :-) class names respectively :-)

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't any convention, one other solution that I haven't seen mentioned here would be to declare

```js
const querySelector = (sel, el) => (el ?? document).querySelector(sel);
const querySelectorAll = (sel, el) => (el ?? document).querySelectorAll(sel);
```

which is inspired from @jave.web's answer in syntax.

The advantages are that this is :

- shorter because you get to ditch `document.` in case you're selecting from it ;
- still completely intelligible for outsiders reading your code. A google search for `querySelector` will immediately yield results, unlike `Selector`.

Also, as Steve said, modern IDEs will autocomplete the name anyways so there no need to make it any shorter. Instead of typing `doc` "tab" `.qu` "tab" you'll be just typing `qu` "tab". To me, this seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function qs(c,s) {
  if(s) {
    return c.querySelector(s)
  } else {
    return document.querySelector(c)
  }
}
function qsa(c,s) {
  if(s) {
    return c.querySelectorAll(s)
  } else {
    return document.querySelectorAll(c)
  }
}
```

Is this a bad solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).